# What are the nouns that can be used to describe something that is out of reach at this moment but a good idea overall

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, slang

I got into this situation in work.  When we got tight schedule and planning and another piece of work is coming through, and it's useful but its out of priority in the moment for my team. And not for another( I know it's messy lol).

I would say something that opposite to `coming in clutch` from sport slang.

I think something like `pie in the sky` but much more achievable - [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141802/what-are-the-nouns-that-can-be-used-to-describe-something-that-is-out-of-reach/141803?newreg=4e4ce97f9afa45daa481e80ffe8a3f22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a specific word/phrase to describe this, so at work I would say something like this

"This is a great idea, but we need to prevent scope creep, so we can prioritize it after we make progress on the current workload"

Comment: that exact description - thanks!